# VueJS: Custom Directive Doesn't Work Inside v-for

Tags: vuejs2

**Problem**

I have a `v-phone` directive that formats the value of a form input. The problem is that it doesn't work inside a `v-for` directive. Can this be remedied? Should it be refactored as a component instead?

**Code**

```
<template v-for="(user in record.users">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input v-model="user.phone" v-phone="user.phone" type="text" />
    <!-- ... -->
</template>

Vue.directive('phone', (el, binding, vnode) => {
    let characters = _.split(binding.value, '');
    let cleanCharacters = _.filter(characters, character => is.alphaNumeric(character));
    let cleanValue = _.join(cleanCharacters, '');
    let formattedValue = cleanValue.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})([a-z0-9])?/, '$1-$2-$3 $4');

    if (_.trim(binding.oldValue) === _.trim(formattedValue)) return;

    _.set(vnode.context, binding.expression, formattedValue);
});
```

**Environment**

- Vue 2.3.2

Comment: how are we going to know the issue without looking at the code for the directive?

Comment: @samayo Added the directive code. To be clear, the directive works outside the `v-for`.

Comment: dont use v-for on templates, if you must then add :key at least

Comment: There is a reason for it and I have keys where needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem(in "vue": "^2.5.2"),but used this to fix it:

```
mounted(){
    this.$nextTick(function () {
     //to fix  v-for 
      let _this=this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        _this.$forceUpdate()
      },20)
    })
```

hope it helps